# Can I establish a connection between WSL2 and MySQL Server running on the same machine?

Tags: mysql, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm new to docker, laravel, and wsl2. I'm currently trying to get an existing project up and running and connected to the database that I've cloned into MySQL server on my local windows environment.

I'm currently running through docker with WSL2 backend and the connection cannot be made between WSL and MySQL server running on windows itself. I've tried `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` in my `.env` settings before realizing its because I'm running in in two different OS on the same computer. I can connect to the main database, I can also create a docker image of MySQL and connect to that, but neither will provide me with the data that's housed inside of my cloned DB which is what I really need access too.

Is there any way to establish a connection on the same machine between WSL and MySQL Server connection running on windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a networking app running on Windows (for example an app running on a NodeJS or SQL server) from your Linux distribution (ie Ubuntu), then you need to use the IP address of your host machine. While this is not a common scenario, you can follow these steps to make it work.

1. Obtain the IP address of your host machine by running this command from your Linux distribution: cat /etc/resolv.conf
2. Copy the IP address following the term: nameserver.
3. Connect to any Windows server using the copied IP address.

reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking